# Xamarin Studio iOS builds taking a few minutes

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm running Xamarin Studio on a 2009 Macbook. It's got 4 GB RAM and a 2.13 GHz processor and Yosemite installed. I've got Xamarin Studio 5.7.1 installed.

I'm trying to debug an iOS universal project with less than 2000 lines of code. Builds are taking up to 5 minutes and frequently not even starting on my iPhone. I'm used to Android development and these build times seem outrageous to me, but maybe this macbook is just not powerful enough to handle development?

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 Minutes for a 2000 LoC project seems too much to me, even considering your hardware specs. Of course, upgrading your hardware should definitely help. We are building around 200k LoC projects in 2 minutes on 2012 hardware, so I doubt it's a hardware issue.

I think something with your build settings is wrong, did you check: [How to speed up MonoTouch compilation time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962562/how-to-speed-up-monotouch-compilation-time)